# Running files from ExternalStorage on Chaquopy

Tags: android, chaquopy

So, I'm pretty new to chaquopy and was wondering if there's anyway to get newly generated (ie: written post-build, while the app is running) .py files to run?

What I mean is: 
Say I save the contents of a textEdit view into a file named 'newFile.py', and it goes into some specified external storage location. Is there anyway to specify that externalStorageDir in advance via source sets (which, as far as I can tell, only apply to src directories and not externalStorage) or something else so that getModule() can later locate it, making the functions in the newly written file callable?

Pretty niche question I know, but this package has me thinking of all kinds of possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify `sys.path` at runtime, like this:

```
py.getModule("sys").get("path").callAttr("append", yourExternalDirectory);
```

And now any Python files in that directory can be loaded using `py.getModule`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! As an aside, how would you best recommend piping stdoutput from a module that just prints, for example "hello world", into a variable/file instead of to the log? I know there are a variety of ways with normal python, but there might be a better way I'm not seeing for piping from chaquopy modules. I can also make it a seperate question if you think other people would find the information useful.

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason why this would be different with Chaquopy than with normal Python, but if you find that it is, please give details in a separate question.